# Hide div is child is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

The URL to the [page is this](https://indianpolitical.in/indian-politician-mp-mla/naveen-patnaik/).

And the screenshot to the questioned area [is this](https://prnt.sc/1x6l0my).

I want, if the accordion has no content, then hide the accordion title itself. Empty accordion elements won't show.

I have used this script for that:

```
jQuery(".su-spoiler-content:empty").parent().hide();
```

But I can't find it doing anything.

Is there anything wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

try that...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.su-spoiler-content').forEach(xDiv=>
  {
  if (xDiv.innerText.trim() === '')
      xDiv.closest('div.su-spoiler').style.display = 'none'
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have "invisible stuff" inside your div.

[image]

I just edit as HTML in the browser and it works

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed before, the element can have some children inside.
Based on other answers (and litle help from my friends), I wrote this piece of jquery code.

```
    $('.accordion-body').each(function (index, element) {
        if (element.children.length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().parent().hide()
        }
    })
```

It may be useful for other people looking for.